# JW Player customization (include toolbar only)

Tags: flash, adobe

I am using jw player for playing audio. can i remove the screen and can i place the only tool bar of the jw player (with out screen). is it possible if yes what can i do thank you

Comment: This is a particularly poor question title, since it doesn't actually state the question, or much info about it.

Comment: I made the title more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','ply','470','24','9','#ffffff');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp3');
  so.addVariable('duration','33');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

See this example provided by Long Tail Video.
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=202